# Flutter WebView problems after updating

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I recently started working on an old flutter app. After updating I now have a webview_flutter problem.

My code ran fine on the current version of the app but now I am facing issues and I don't know what to do.

```
import 'package:hvd/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

// This page shows the Bufkes website (https://bufkes.nl) for ordering online.

class Bufkes extends StatefulWidget {
  Bufkes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Bufkes createState() => _Bufkes();
}

class _Bufkes extends State<Bufkes> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: SideBar(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Bufkes (Tiel)'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://bufkes.nl',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted)));
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong? In the current code it says that I am not using the webview_flutter plugin...

Tank you all.

Comment: Have you updated the minSdkVersion to 19 in your android/app/build.gradle ?

Comment: Yes this is set to 20. I now see in the documentation that when you migrate from V3 to V4 there are some breaking changes but I don't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `webview_flutter` package had indeed breaking changes a few months ago.
The Widget is now called `WebViewWidget`, and is used with a WebViewController.

Update your code to use them, like:

```dart
class _Bufkes extends State<Bufkes> {
  final WebViewController _webViewController = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _webViewController
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://bufkes.nl'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: SideBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Bufkes (Tiel)'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _webViewController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code did the trick! Thank you!